# Best way to get the relevant log file from ~/.ros/log

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Log files in `~/.ros/log` are quite useful especially when diagnosing someone's issue remotely. What's not so easy is to figure out which `.log` file or directory is the one that the user is dealing with since there can be quite a few number of files/directories.

An easy workaround is to ask the user to run the problematic run and make a tarball immediately out of the most recent file/directory, found at the top of the result of `ls -l`. This is not, however, something that the users always are happy to do.

Is there a ROS way to get it done nicely?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134841/best-way-to-get-the-relevant-log-file-from-%7E/.ros/log/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2014-03-02

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The roslaunch-logs command will show the current log directory that is in use.

It's documented in more detail on the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools#roslaunch-logs)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3